# How do I absolute position a div from left to the right using media queries?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

Im having problems positioning a div to the right using media queries.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body,html { height:100%; }

.container {
  width:1000px;
  height:100%;
  background:#eee;
  position:relative;
}

.left {
  height:100%;
  width:200px;
  background:orange;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .left {
    position:absolute !important;
    right:0 !important;
   }
 }
```

The left div is absolutely positioned to the left. I want to absolutely position that same div to the right when my media query is triggered at 700px width.

The problem is that it wont do it! I tried using !important. I tried to reiterate the position in the media query. NOTHING!

The weird part is that if I start off with the div absolutely positioned to the right , and with media queries, absolutely position the div to the left. IT WORKS! 
What? Why?

**DIV absolutely positioned to the left, with media query to bring the DIV to the right.

DOESNT WORK**

http://jsfiddle.net/zfdmmyaz/

**DIV absolutely positioned to the right, with media query to bring the DIV to the left.

THIS WORKS**

http://jsfiddle.net/md07a02t/

How do I get this to work? How can I get my absolutely left positioned div to absolutely position itself all the way to the right when media query is triggered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reset the `left` value to `auto`, and then set the `right` value.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gpujeu8p/)

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .left {
        position: absolute;
        left: auto;
        right: 0;
        background: lime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked! Could you explain why this works? Why is it that if I start off absolute positioned to the right, I can absolutely position all the way to the left using media queries with no problems, but not vice versa?

Comment: You only set the left or right (top or bottom) but not both at the same time, except when you want the element to stretch it's width/height to cover the entire relative container or so.

Comment: A quick [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vffn99oy/) to show when happens if you set all the values :)

Answer (score 0):

Use float instead of left. Also, you don't need to make the .left div absolute since it will be absolutely positioned to it's relative container.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">Content</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body,html { height:100%; }

.container {
  width:1000px;
  height:100%;
  background-color:#eee;
  position:relative;
  border: 1px #000000 solid;
}

.left {
  height:100%;
  width:200px;
  background-color:orange;
  float: left;
}

.clear {
    clear:both;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .container {
        width:100%;
    }

    .left {
        float: right !important;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative. I tried using floats on my template and it works too. It does take up space as it moves my divs to make room for that div. I need something that goes over the template without moving anything. Thanks!